# How to convert a string of hex shellcode to an unsigned char array in C++?

Tags: c++, shellcode

I'm trying to create a .dll file that executes shellcode when called in my virtual Windows environment. The problem is, the shellcode, which is a sequence of hexadecimal values in a format similar to "\xfc\x00\xff\x00\x00...", is initially decoded from base64 and stored as a C++ string because of the decode function I'm using. As a result, I can't perform something like:

```
void (*func)()
func = (void (*)()) decoded_shellcode;
(void)(*func)();
```

I want to convert the string to an array of unsigned chars in C++ because that appears to execute properly in the virtual environment. Is there any way I can do this, or at least have the string be interpreted as executable code?

Comment: The rule is as follows: the symbols x = 'a' to 'f' change to (x - 'a' - 9, be attentive, always constant 'a'). The symbols x = '0' to '9' you change to (x - '0', be attentive, always constant '0'). Two codes you combine in a single byte by ((x1 << 8) | x2)

Comment: @armagedescu — did you mean `((x1 << 4) | x2)`?

Comment: Thanks! I managed to convert the string to an unsigned char array successfully using the methods you guys suggested. :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, thanks for sharp eye :)